# Ensure that end date is greater than start date and in the proper range

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I have a form with two date fields `start` date and `end` date.  The form has dynamically created rows each having these two date fields.

I have set the start date and end date within a range using the `minDate` and `maxDate` features of `datepicker`.  It works except when I select the end date it should be greater than start date and it should also be within the date range.

Comment: Can you post the part of your code that has a problem? Also, what kind of datepicker are you using? There's a lot of library for datepicker out there.

Comment: Em using jquery.datepick.js

Comment: If anything, you can easily make your own validation of that. Make a function that gets the values of the 2 dates, if(endDate<=startDate){ /* throw error to user */ }

Answer (score 0):

You could alternatively add your own validation to the process.

Retrieve the values of the date input fields, use the `Date()` function to get a date value, and make a condition around it.

Note that this example uses European standards: dd/mm/yyyy

```js
function validateDates(){
    var result = true;
 
    var start_date = $('#startDate').val();
    start_date = new Date(""+start_date);

    var end_date = $('#endDate').val();
    end_date = new Date(""+end_date);
  
    if(end_date <= start_date)
    {
        result = false;
        $('#dateError').html("End date must be later than start date!");
        $('#additionalText').html("Try changing the dates, and try again.");
    }
    
    return result;
}

function testFunction(){
    if( validateDates() ) {
         $('#additionalText').html("");
         $('#dateError').attr("id","success");
         $('#success').html("Success!");
    }
}
```

```css
#dateError{
    color: red;
}

#success{
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="startDate" name="startDate" placeholder="Enter start date" value="12/10/2018">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="endDate" name="endDate" placeholder="Enter end date" value="10/10/2018">
<br /><br />
<span id="dateError"></span>
<br />
<span id="additionalText"></span>
<br /><br />

<button onclick="testFunction();">Test</button>
```

Comment: Thanku martin, i have tried to put some validation of my own but it is working perfect for first row only. When i add more rows this validation does work on them :(

Comment: Ah, you didn't mention anything about multiple rows. In case of multiple rows, don't go by id's, go by class instead, loop through them and compare the values in a similar fashion. It will give you your desired result.